# Pandas: rolling total of checked out vs checked in items

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large data set that I need to calculate the number of checked out items vs the number of checked in items.

Sample data where `rollingTotalCheckedOut` describes the expected value. While items are checked out, the number of checked out items increases. When items are checked back in, the number of checked out items decreases.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
            ['A', 1624990605, 1627102404, 1],
            ['A', 1624990635, 1625015061, 2],
            ['A', 1624990790, 1624991096, 3],
            ['A', 1624990790, 1624990913, 4],
            ['A', 1624990822, 1624991711, 5],
            ['A', 1624990945, 1624991096, 5],
            ['A', 1624991036, 1624991066, 6],
            ['A', 1624991067, 1624991188, 6],
            ],
        columns = ['ID', 'out_ts', 'in_ts', 'rollingTotalCheckedOut'])
```

```
# some helpers
df['checkoutTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['out_ts'], unit='s', origin='unix')
df['checkinTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['in_ts'], unit='s', origin='unix')
```

I am not even sure how to best describe this problem. What is my strategy here / how to frame and tackle this problem? A rolling window does not seem suitable because, in this case, the first row is "checked out" for a very long time.

Comment: checkout time always goes before checkin time in one row?

Comment: is your rolling total actually just the number of checkout items at the exact point of time `out_ts`?

Comment: Yes, in one row, checkinTime can never come before checkoutTime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I got. not exactly your calculation but I can't immediately see an error. Will check again. But honestly I am not sure why you have a 5 in the end. Previous period ended but new just started.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
            ['A', 1624990605, 1627102404, 1],
            ['A', 1624990635, 1625015061, 2],
            ['A', 1624990790, 1624991096, 3],
            ['A', 1624990790, 1624990913, 4],
            ['A', 1624990822, 1624991711, 5],
            ['A', 1624990945, 1624991096, 5],
            ['A', 1624991036, 1624991066, 6],
            ['A', 1624991067, 1624991188, 5],
            ],
        columns = ['ID', 'out_ts', 'in_ts', 'rollingTotalCheckedOut'])

df["full_interval"] = df["out_ts"].astype("str") + "_" + df["in_ts"].astype("str")

df_out= df.drop(columns = ["in_ts"])
df_out["ts"] = df_out["out_ts"]
df_out["op"] = "out"
df_out["op_val"] = 1
df_in= df.drop(columns = ["out_ts"])
df_in["ts"] = df_in["in_ts"]
df_in["op"] = "in"
df_in["op_val"] = -1



df_stacked = pd.concat([df_out, df_in]).sort_values("ts")

df_stacked["rollingTotalCheckedOut"] = df_stacked["op_val"].cumsum()
df_stacked = df_stacked.sort_values("out_ts").dropna(subset=["out_ts"])

df = df.merge(df_stacked.loc[:,["ID","full_interval", "rollingTotalCheckedOut"]], how="left", on=["ID", "full_interval"])
df = df.drop(columns=["full_interval"])
df
```

Output:

```
ID  out_ts  in_ts   rollingTotalCheckedOut_x    rollingTotalCheckedOut_y
0   A   1624990605  1627102404  1   1
1   A   1624990635  1625015061  2   2
2   A   1624990790  1624991096  3   3
3   A   1624990790  1624990913  4   4
4   A   1624990822  1624991711  5   5
5   A   1624990945  1624991096  5   5
6   A   1624991036  1624991066  6   6
7   A   1624991067  1624991188  5   6
```

Comment: Definitely think I had an error in my expected Out; just looked at it again and updated it which looks like it matches your result. What would you call this process? Is it really some sort of rolling total?

Comment: "total_checked_out_at_period_start" I would call it. Or "total_checked_out_at_out_ts"